# AspxGridView visiblerowcount

Tags: asp.net

I have one nested aspxgridview in aspxpagecontrol. When I click on some button I want to get number of rows in grid. That's ok. But When I use filter and get no rows in grid, click on some button, I'm still getting 1000 rows, but no row is visible.

I don't know, where is the problem :/

Thanks.

Comment: Show your code or else its hard to see where youve gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to use the VisibleRowCount in the databound event. I raised a [support ticket with devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q458877) and they said to try using the BeforeGetCallbackResult.

Without seeing your code it's hard to say but maybe you can store the RowCount in a variable and set it in both the DataBound and BeforeGetCallbackResult events. During a filter it would be set twice but BeforeGetCallbackResult will override DataBound and you'll get the correct result.

Failing that build a simple demo and raise a ticket with DevExpress and there is a DevExpress tag you can use on SO.